# Windows authentication not working - invalid credentials passed to the SQL Server

Tags: iis-7.5, windows-authentication, ntlm

I am stuck at the moment on trying to configure the Windows authentication on a web site.

The site is configured (in IIS 7.5) as follows:
Windows authentication and ASP.NET Impersonation - Enabled.

The 'Enable Kernel-mode authentication' is checked. 
Providers section contain all 3 possible: Negotiate, NTLM, Negotiate:Kerberos.

The site connects to a SQL Server using Windows authentication as well. 
The Web server is marked as trusted for delegation for the SQL server.

When I browse the site locally from the web server everything works; when I browse it from a client computer I get the well known error "Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'"

I read I should set some SPNs - but in my case - to what\whom ?...
The access to the SQL Server is done individually to users (also, the Web server, SQL server and the users accessing the site are in the same domain; the application pool also uses a domain account)

An advice would be much appreciated ...

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting "Anonymous Logon" because you have anonymous logon enabled.
Try enabling only Windows authentication and ASP.NET Impersonation and disabling the rest
Also might help to check the internet explorer security settings for the 'zone' you're in from the client computer (i'm guessing internet) at the very end set internet explorer to prompt for user name and password

Comment: The Anonymous authentication was disabled in my IIS settings.

Comment: Finally I did a workaround by using SQL Server authentication on the DB side; how ever if I wanted further to make use of Windows authentication both on Web and MS SQL servers as I understand I would have needed to configure the Kerberos Constrained delegation on my servers.